# Do PS2 Keyboards work on Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10, ps2

I was just told that PS2 Keyboards aren't compatible with windows 10.

Is this true.  I was under the impression that they should work fine?

Comment: Where did you read that PS2 keyboards and mice don't work with Windows 10?

Comment: The company my parents bought their new PC from said that.  (I didn't believe them but didn't have any proof at the time)

Comment: If the PC has a PS2 port then it will work on any operating system the PC supports.

Comment: Well that what I thought.  The reason it was questioned was that when they plugged their (working) PS2 keyboard into the PC, it didn't work.

Comment: PS2's nature is that a keyboard or mouse will only work when it is plugged in and then the pc is booted up. Unplugging the device then reinserting the plug never worked, you always needed to reboot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Microsoft, Windows 10 does still accept PS/2 inputs. However there might be issues with drivers, this [forum discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_devices/does-windows-10-technical-preview-support-a-ps2/9b770eb9-e56f-4131-b9d8-2bd406098c04?auth=1) explains the process for troubleshooting it.

Below is a direct quote from the **Microsoft engineer** in that thread detailing the various troubleshooting methods:

> Method 1.
>
> Plug the device and run the hardware troubleshooter. Once this is
> done, restart the computer and check the status.
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> - Press the ‘Windows + W’ key on the keyboard.
> - Type troubleshooting in the search box and then press enter.
> - Click hardware and sound and run the Hardware and Devices Troubleshooter.
> - Follow the On screen instructions. Once this is done, restart the computer and check the status.
>
> Method 2.
>
> You may update the PS2 mouse driver from Device Manager manually and
> check if this helps.
>
> 1. Press (Windows key + X) and click on “Device Manager”.
> 2. Expand “Mouse” or “Mice and other pointing devices”.
> 3. Right click on the driver and select “Update Driver Software”. Once this is done, restart the computer and check if the issue persists.
>
> Further, you may also look for optional updates in Windows Updates to
> see if there are any additional updates related to this device and
> install them as required.
>
> Method 3.
>
> If the driver update does not help then I would suggest you to
> completely uninstall the USB driver and reinstall it to check if this
> helps.
>
> Follow these steps.
>
> - Press “Windows key + X” and click on “Device Manager”.
> - In the list of devices, you should see the “Mouse” or “Mice and other pointing devices”.
> - Right click on the device driver and then select "Uninstall".
> - In the uninstall dialog, make sure you select the option to delete the driver package from the system. This causes the driver package installed earlier to be deleted.
> - In the Action menu of Device manager, select “Scan for Hardware
>   changes” option. This will force the computer to recognize any
>   hardware changes. Once the driver is installed, close all windows and
>   restart the computer.

I don't have a PS/2 keyboard to test these for you.

Comment: For me, "Windows key + W" in Method 1 brings up WINDOWS INK WORKSPACE.

Comment: Tricky if one just has a PS/2 keyboard to enter the password to log on..?

Comment: you'll need to have a USB keyboard to do the troubleshooting like this (or better, with USB mouse as well)

Comment: Doesn't work. This shouldn't be the selected answer.
I've worked on hundreds of win10 machines, Guest's answer below is correct.

Comment: It might be a co-incidence, but yesterday Windows 10 installed some update and since rebooting my PS/2 keyboard is not detected any more; not even in BIOS.

Comment: @nsandersen: You can use the on-screen keyboard if you have a mouse, if the option was not actively disabled.

Answer (score 25):

If it doesn't work with a simple plug and play, do this:

1. Open Regedit.
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Services > i8042prt
3. Set the default value for "Start" to 1.
4. Restart your machine.

Comment: worked for me. The value was set to 3.

Comment: It worked also for me. Also in my case the value was set to 3. The PS/2 keyboard had stopped to work once that I had used an USB keyboard for a short time

Comment: Can you please explain what this actually does?

Comment: `i8042prt` is the Windows driver for standard PS/2 keyboards and mice https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/ps-2--i8042prt--driver. This part of the Windows Registry contains settings for the driver's corresponding service (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/hklm-system-currentcontrolset-services-registry-tree).  The start type `SERVICE_SYSTEM_START ` (`1`), causes it to be started automatically during OS initialization. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/what-determines-when-a-driver-is-loaded

Comment: (The name comes from the Intel 8042 microcontroller that was used as the keyboard controller in the IBM PC AT)

Comment: Worked for me, but required value of `0` ("load by bootloader and start during kernel init before other drivers") to be set instead of `1`

Answer (score 18):

Adding to [Guest's answer](/a/1090314):

In the Registry Editor, under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt`, the `Start` key should be changed from `3` to `1`.

More detail about what the settings mean (from http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/values-for-the-start-registry-entry.html):

> | Value | Start Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | Boot | Specifies a driver that is loaded (but not started) by the boot loader. If no errors occur, the driver is started during kernel initialization prior to any non-boot drivers being loaded. |
> | 1 | System | Specifies a driver that loads and starts during kernel initialization after drivers with a Start value of 0 have been started. |
> | 2 | Auto Load | Specifies a driver or service that is initialized at system startup by Session Manager (Smss.exe) or the Services Controller (Services.exe). |
> | 3 | Load on Demand | Specifies a driver or service that the Service Control Manager (SCM) will start only on demand. These drivers have to be started manually by calling a Win32 SCM application programming interface (API), such as the Services snap-in. |
> | 4 | Disable | Specifies a disabled (not started) driver or service. |
> | 5 | Delayed Start | Specifies that less-critical services will start shortly after startup to allow the operating system to be responsive to the user sooner. This start type was first introduced in Windows Vista. |

I had a PS/2 touchpad that was unresponsive in Windows 10. After changing this key to 1 and rebooting, the touchpad now works.

Comment: Great, the SkyJT-338 is back in business! :)

Comment: Remember, when you turn off the computer, do it with the uppercase shift pressed, otherwise it may not turn off but hibernate and not apply the change.

Comment: IT WORKS! What a lifesaver, thank you so much for this