# Windows 10 doesn't see PS/2 keyboard

Tags: windows-10, ps2, ps2-keyboard

The PS/2 keyboard is available in the BIOS. But after the Windows 10 system is booted, keyboard is not detected.

Comment: Seems related https://superuser.com/questions/996001/do-ps2-keyboards-work-on-windows-10?rq=1 . More information on your system would be nice

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

1. Go to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters`.
2. Set parameters `OverrideKeyboardSubtype`, `OverrideKeyboardType`,
       `StartOverride` (if exists) to `1`.
3. Reboot the system.

Comment: You really should cite and quote your sources

Comment: I was able to find an English [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/ps-2--i8042prt--driver) without a problem by the way.

Comment: I am not sure what my voting record has to do with you not citing your source.  I review hundreds of questions and answers.  Unfortunately a good chunk of those are low quality questions and a vast majority of the answers are comments submitted as answers.  **If you have a problem with my voting record then I encourage you to bring it to the attention of a moderator.**  We are encourage to vote on answers and questions.  It seems you would have no problem if I upvoted more then downvoted which is hypocritical. .

Comment: Worth pointing out that, it does not appear that 0x1 is a valid value for `OverrideKeyboardSubtype` and `OverrideKeyboardType`, with the first [documented value](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976378.aspx) being 0x2 not 0x1 also worth pointing out there is no default value for `OverrideKeyboardType` and the value depends on the PS2 keyboard you are actually using.  Likewise the value you should be using for`StartOverride ` is `3` instead of `1` and it appears the value is updated to`0` after the override is accepted/read.

Comment: It would be safe to set `OverrideKeyboardSubtype ` to `0x0` unless you had an OEM specific keyboard, even then, it would only be required to be something other then `0x0` if you wanted those additional keys to work.

Comment: I took a look at your source, it makes no mention of those registry keys, so I am confused.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the additional information. Now I'll know. However, the original method worked. I changed two parameters: `OverrideKeyboardSubtype` and `OverrideKeyboardType` to `1`. Parameter `StartOverride` was not. Maybe a little lucky.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5z_pUmEegh8RWVta3ZIS2VWUTQ/view) is a copy of the page. See the 6th item.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly on Windows 8.1 also. Many thanks!