# PS/2 2in1 mouse/keyboard connector is not working

Tags: windows, connector, ps2

I have a motherboard that has a PS/2 2in1 connector (green|purple). If I plug a keyboard into it, it works in BIOS, but doesn't work in Windows. I tried a couple of videos that messed a little with the Windows registry editor, but nothing worked.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do PS2 Keyboards work on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/996001/do-ps2-keyboards-work-on-windows-10)

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know, I've tested many of these solutions beforehand, but nothing worked. However, I have almost the same motherboard the same (Windows 10) OS and the same CPU on which PC PS/2 keyboard works perfectly. The only difference between the motherboards is the other doesn't have 2in1 but 2 separate PS/2 keyboard and mouse connectors.